# Visual Studio Extensions and Visual Studio 11 Dev. Preview

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-extensions

I am unable to install lots of extensions to Visual Studio 11 Dev. Preview. It keeps saying `This extension is not installable on any currently installed products.`.

I have only VS 11 Dev. Preview installed on my machine.

- Is this only happening to me?
- Hasn't MS implemented the support for VS 11 to install the extensions made for VS 2010?
- Is MS out of its mind (**I don't think so but you never know**) and not going to support those?

Comment: Are you using the Express that comes pre-installed on Windows 8, or the Ultimate you download separately?

Comment: @KateGregory no, the ultimate one. I am using it on windows server 2008 R2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rename the extension to be a zip file, edit the manifest in the file to target vs11.

Comment: here is the blog post: http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/make-the-visual-studio-extensions-compatible-with-visual-studio-11-developer-preview

Answer (score 3):

VS 2011 Developer Preview is just that - the developer preview.  It is not a production release and therefore not complete.  I am not surprised that it does not currently support most extensions from 2010.

Whether 2010 extensions will be fully supported in 2011 is anyone's guess, but I suspect most will work.

Comment: Unfortunately.  I very much miss my extensions.