# Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design, Version=10.0.0.0 is for Visual Studio Developer Preview 11

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, dbcontext, visual-studio-2012

I am trying something here but keep failing.

I have Visual Studio Developer Preview installed on a Windows Server 2008 R2. As you know, for  now VS extensions are not compatible with VS 11 Dev Preview but I found a workaround:

[Visual Studio Extensions and Visual Studio 11 Dev. Preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726121/visual-studio-extensions-and-visual-studio-11-dev-preview)

I installed [ADO.NET C# DbContext Generator](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7812b04c-db36-4817-8a84-e73c452410a2) on VS 11 but when I try to run the code generation, I am getting the following error:

> Error: this template attempted to load component assembly
>   'Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. For more information on this problem
>   and how to enable this template, please see documentation on
>   Customizing Project Templates.

I checked from the add reference page, there is no dll like above.

Any chance I can get this work with VS 11 Dev. Preview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I solved the problem but I am not sure it is legitimate or not.

when you unzip the extension, navigate to `T/code/` folder inside that, there is a zip file called **DbContextCS.zip**. Unzip that as well, and you will see file called **ADONETArtifactGenerator_DbContextCSharp.vstemplate**

Open this up with text editor and change this code:

```
  <WizardExtension>
    <Assembly>Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a</Assembly>
    <FullClassName>Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VisualStudio.ModelWizard.AddArtifactGeneratorWizard</FullClassName>
  </WizardExtension>
```

To this one:

```
  <WizardExtension>
    <Assembly>Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a</Assembly>
    <FullClassName>Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VisualStudio.ModelWizard.AddArtifactGeneratorWizard</FullClassName>
  </WizardExtension>
```

Pack everything back together and install the extension, when you run the code gen., you will have no problem.