# Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design, Visual Studio 2013 - error adding ADO.NET

Tags: visual-studio-2013, entity-framework-6

I have this error while trying to add ADO.NET Entity Data Model. I'm targeting .NET 4.5.1, use Visual Studio 2013 and Windows 8.1. I tried reinstalling nuget, VS, frameworks and also [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8416591/microsoft-data-entity-design-version-10-0-0-0-is-for-visual-studio-developer-pr). Nothing works : / Anyone having the same issue?

[image]

Comment: This is related to your other post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19664833/metadata-file-not-found-data-entity-model (note that it cannot find the same dll). You could try using procmon (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to check where VS is actually looking for the missing assembly and if it can find the file. If the file can be found you can turn on Fusion logging (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255669/how-to-enable-assembly-bind-failure-logging-fusion-in-net) to check why loading the assembly fails

Comment: Yes, maybe it is. I "solved" problem by creating and adding ado.net entity at pc that I knew that had properly and simply, without customisation, installed VS. I'll have to try formatting...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried targeting to older version? f.e. 4.5

Comment: Yes, I did. I also tried FE 4, but it has no option to add ADO.NET EM.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: I changed the framework version, repaired, installed updates, copied the entity framework folder from other PC and nothing happened, eventually i run the setup and added the SQL components (Entity Framework Designer) and is fixed now.